# count number of words per each line

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, sparklyr

I am trying to move an R code into spark using sparklyr, I am facing troubles with some of the functions in order to do the following things:

-Count the total number of words in a row: for example 
word= "Hello how are you" , number of words: 4
-Count the total number of character in the first word: for example:
word= "Hello how are you" , number of characters in the first word: 5

-Count the total number of character in the first word: for example:
word= "Hello how are you" , number of characters in the second word: 3

I tried with dpylr and stringr package but I can't get what I need.

I connect to a spark session

```
install.packages("DBI")
install.packages("ngram")

require(DBI)
require(sparklyr)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
require(stringi)
require(base)
require(ngram)

# Spark Config 

config <- spark_config()
config$spark.executor.cores <- 2
config$spark.executor.memory <- "4G"

spark <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client",version = "2.3.0",app_name = "Test", config=config)
```

Then I try to retrieve some data with an SQL statement

```
test_query<-sdf_sql(spark,"SELECT ID, NAME  FROM table.name LIMIT 10")
```

```
NAME <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
ID<-c(1,2,3)

test_query<-data.frame(NAME,ID) # ( this is the example data, here it is in R data frame, but I have on a Spark Data Frame)
```

When I try to do feature engineering I got an error in the last line

```
test_query<-test_query %>% 
mutate(Total_char=nchar(NAME))%>% # this works good
mutate(Name_has_numbers=str_detect(NAME,"[[:digit:]]"))%>% # Works good
mutate(Total_words=str_count(NAME, '\\w+')) # I got an error
```

The error message I am getting is this one: Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'STR_COUNT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

-Count the total number of words in a row: for example 
word= "Hello how are you" , number of words: 4
-Count the total number of character in the first word: for example:
word= "Hello how are you" , number of characters in the first word: 5

-Count the total number of character in the first word: for example:
word= "Hello how are you" , number of characters in the second word: 3

Comment: please add the error message to your question so that we have a better idea of what is causing your problem.

Comment: if you change `nchar(NAME)` to `nchar(as.character(NAME))` your code eorks good

Comment: Indeed, just like @JilberUrbina said your code was correct. You just need to add `nchar(as.character(NAME))` and it should work correctly. Jilber Urbina, I suggest you add your comment to an answer since it resolve OP problem.

Comment: Just notice both of you guys has the same last name and it is the first time I heard it haha.

Comment: The error message I am getting is this one:  Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'STR_COUNT'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.                                    @JilberUrbina actually the line which is not working is this one: mutate(Total_words=str_count(NAME, '\\w+'))

Comment: @Gainz please see comment above

Comment: @ScottUrbina Well your code is working very well for me at the moment. It seems like a SQL/R error and not a R error. If I'm not wrong this error is from the `sparklyr` package. Can you try this please : `stringr::str_count()` instead of just `str_count()`

Comment: @Gainz I have tried like `stringr::str_count()` but now I am gettting another error which it is:  Error in stri_count_boundaries(string, opts_brkiter = opts(pattern)) : 
  object 'NAME_NORM_LONG' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(tidyverse)
> test_query %>% 
      mutate(NAME = as.character(NAME),
        word_count = str_count(NAME, "\\w+"),     # Count the total number of words in a row
           N_char_first_word = nchar((gsub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", NAME)))  #Count the total number of character in the first word
                    )
        NAME ID word_count N_char_first_word
1   John Doe  1          2                 4
2 Peter Gynn  2          2                 5
3 Jolie Hope  3          2                 5
```

Comment: Seems that gsub and str_count are not working on sparklyr, I am having this error `Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'GSUB'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'`